# TeeChart - What's the name of this part and how to remove it

Tags: c#, uwp, teechart

I'm learning how to use TeeChart and there is this part that always bothering me. I am not that familiar with chart so I don't know what's the name of it. My question is how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: thats the legend

Comment: http://support.steema.com/viewtopic.php?t=1914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the Steema documentation ([here](https://www.steema.com/docs/TeeChartNETReference.htm)) and found that you can use the `TChart.Legend` property to control this area of the chart. From the API, it seems this should work:

```
chart.Legend.Visible = false;
```